# gFTP - Received File Is (Allegedly) Larger Than Original!

Tags: linux, ftp, file-copy

I am using gFTP to transfer a large gzip file (the gFTP window says it is ~3.7GB). However an hour after saying it the transfer was 99% completed and had 00:00:00 time remaining and says the received file is now ~4.9GB. After over 4 hours running I am reluctant to stop it but how can I tell if it is working properly?

I cannot access the remote machine unless I stop the process so I cannot see how big the file is with an `ls -l`.

Comment: Are you sure you can't make a second ftp connection to the remote computer from a different terminal?

Comment: What operating system is the remote system running? It could have a version of the ftp server that was not compiled to handle files larger than 2GB properly.

Comment: The firewall, not under my control, currently only allows one remote connection. As it a prototyping environment it does not have 24x7 support like the main VMs so I cannot get anyone to open up access or check for me.

The OS is exactly the same as mine here  - 64-bit Mint.

Comment: You can tell if the file is corrupted by running `gunzip -l < filename` and seeing if it outputs any errors. There's a CRC after each file member in the gziped file.

Comment: You might also double-check that `gFTP` is downloading the file in _binary_ mode, not ASCII mode.  ASCII mode tends to be the default transfer mode, sadly, and ASCII translation of a binary file (such as a gzip file) could result in the behavior you're seeing.